# ASP.NET, Xunit tests fail: System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, xunit

I'm trying to unit test an existing solution. It's a big project that I further have no power over to change things (like MVC version).

In this solution, I'm trying to create my own unit tests that test my controllers and repository. So I create my mock repository and my controller that I want tested that uses this repository.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var mockRepository = new Mock<IChatRepository>();
        ChatController controller = new ChatController(mockRepository.Object);

        ActionResult result = controller.ChatOverview(1);
    }
```

However, as soon as I call an action on the controller and run the test it shows me the following error:

[image: Unit test fail with MissingMethodException]

I'm not really quite sure what to do with this error. I've tried adding several PackageReferences in the .csproj file to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled session state in your application properly? The [following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-session-state) describes how to enable session state in .net core 3.0.

You have to add the following lines to your Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
  // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  // Make the session cookie essential
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

app.UseSession();
```

Also, you need to initialize a ControllerContext when creating your controller from a unit test before invoking the controller action:

```cs
var session = new Mock<ISession>();

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
{
  HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
  {
    Session = session.Object
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I'm quite lost how to add these things. I'm sure session state works as It's an existing application and there have been plenty of usages for the session. When I use the second part in my unit test however it doesn't recognize "HttpContext" saying: `Reference to type 'HttpContextBase' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found`